# Wordpress: How to delete post with specific content automatically

Tags: php, cron, wordpress

I want to delete Wordpress posts with a specific content automatically with WP-Crontrol (or maybe a better solution I don't know yet).
I have added the following cron job but it doesn't do anything:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE 'Content which should result in a deletion of this post'" );
  if ($result){
    foreach($result as $pageThing){
      wp_delete_post($pageThing);
    }
  }
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-crontrol/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require_once('absolute-path/wp-load.php')` at the top of the cron script then run your script. What you have now should work.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help:

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ); require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' ); global $wpdb; $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE 'Content which should result in a deletion of this post'" ); if ($result){ foreach($result as $pageThing){ wp_delete_post($pageThing); } }

Comment: Why didn't it help? What happens when you run the PHP script from bash or from the web?